# How to prevent .bash_history from being used to rebuild history

Tags: bash, command-history

We use custom history files which get backed up per user. When someone does a `history -c` we notice that after they log back in there is history in the buffer again and it seems to come from `/root/.bash_history`. This adds back in history that we do not want in the buffer, which then rolls into our custom files and skews the data. How can we prevent this from happening? FYI in case it helps the way we login is with our std account, then `sudo -i` to get root.

Answer (score 1):

Your use case isn't clear to me. But as far as I understand you want not to save [history](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-History-Facilities) between sessions, and that's easy: add `unset HISTFILE` to `~/.bashrc` (that's `/root/.bashrc` for the history while under `sudo -i`).

Comment: I spoke too soon. This is not getting me the desired result. I am going to edit my question so there is no confusion as to what I am looking to do.